# Can anyone share Bundle product import sheet?

Tags: import, importexport, bundled-product

I want to import bundle products through import sheet (csv), but it's getting me error. Infact i export the product and import, but it still showing error and not importing.

Can anyone share me tested bundle product import sheet sample?

Comment: are you getting error : Product type is not supported in rows: 1?

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento does not allow you to import Bundled products (Via default Magento or Dataflow). I would recommend using Magmi as it allows you to create Bundled (and Downloadable) products via a CSV import.

Link to the documentation - http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page